# Remove all chars in java string, except '0' and '1'

Tags: java, string

How can I remove all characters being neither '0' nor '1' in a string, so that the final string consists of only 0s and 1s? I'm using Java 8.

My solution with a for loop (I think it's not the most efficient way):

```
String before = "012940124810";
String after = new String();

for(int i = 0; i < before.length();  i++) {
  if(before.charAt(i) == '0' || before.charAt(i) == '1') {
    after += before.charAt(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `regex` and `replaceAll` method

```
 String out = str.replaceAll("[^01]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this you just take a index variable starting from 0 and delete character by charcter if it is not 0 or 1 if you found just move index to next location without deleting it. If you need more help attach some code so that i will tell you perfect solution